# sssd and Active Directory user does not exist in CentOS

Tags: centos, active-directory, sssd

When I try to do a `su user1@ADREALM.COM` I get a "user does not exist" message.

user1@ADREALM.COM exists in Active Directory. I can do `kinit user1@ADREALM.COM` successfully and get a ticket. Here are the steps I did:

1. I have MIT KDC on CentOS 7 CENTOSREALM.COM and Active Directory realm  ADREALM.COM
2. On CentOS I did `realm join ADREALM.COM` which gave "* Successfully enrolled machine in realm". I can see the centos hostname in Active Directory Computers container.
3. But I cannot login to  the CentOS server with user1@ADREALM.COM this user exists in AD.

Where do I look for errors or steps to debug this issue?

The sssd.conf content:

```
[sssd]
domains = adrealm.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/adrealm.com]
ad_server = adrealm.com
ad_domain = adrealm.com
krb5_realm = ADREALM.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
debug_level = 3
```

Comment: What does your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file look like?

Comment: [sssd]
domains = adrealm.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/adrealm.com]
ad_server = adrealm.com
ad_domain = adrealm.com
krb5_realm = ADREALM.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
debug_level = 3

Comment: @Christophe Drevet-Droguet above is /etc/sssd/sssd.conf: 
In addition I checked forward and reverse dns from centos to Active Dir works fine.
I have updated /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf, /etc/krb5.conf based on many suggestions. Thx!!

Comment: Also if I get this error with ldapwhoami: 


ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI -H ldap://adserver1.adrealm.com
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)

Comment: Did you try to use the name `user1@adrealm.com`? I'm sure LDAP is not case sensitive, but I think sssd is. If you want to use upper case, it should be also in the sssd domain name (`[domain/ADREALM.COM]`). If it's not that, do you have some errors in `/var/log/sssd/` files?

Comment: Also, the `ad_server` should contain a list of AD servers near your machine, such as: `ad_server = srv1.adrealm.com,srv3.adrealm.com,srv4.adrealm.com`. I don't see anything else that could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help on this :)  
I changed the ad_Server to the actual hostname svr.adrealm.com and restarted sssd. I tried both user1@adrealm.com and user1@ADREALM.COM same not found error. I ran wireshark and it gives below error:  
error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN (7)
Realm: ADREALM.COM
Server Name (Service and Host): ldap/adrealm.com
  
and also another error:
error_code: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN (7)
Realm: ADREALM.COM
Server Name (Service and Instance): krbtgt/COM
  
Below is the sssd_adrealm.log:

Comment: (Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [ad_sasl_log] (0x0040): SASL: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [sasl_bind_send] (0x0020): ldap_sasl_bind failed (-2)[Local error]
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [sasl_bind_send] (0x0080): Extended failure message: [SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)]

Comment: (Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [fo_resolve_service_send] (0x0020): No available servers for service 'AD'
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [sdap_id_op_connect_done] (0x0020): Failed to connect, going offline (5 [Input/output error])
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [be_run_offline_cb] (0x0080): Going offline. Running callbacks.
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [ad_subdomains_refresh_connect_done] (0x0020): Unable to connect to LDAP [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: (Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [be_run_offline_cb] (0x0080): Going offline. Running callbacks.
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [sdap_dyndns_get_addrs_done] (0x0080): No LDAP server is available, dynamic DNS update is skipped in offline mode.
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [sdap_dyndns_update_addrs_done] (0x0040): Can't get addresses for DNS update
(Fri Sep  7 10:51:42 2018) [sssd[be[adrealm.com]]] [ad_dyndns_sdap_update_done] (0x0040): Dynamic DNS update failed [1432158241]: Dynamic DNS update not possible while offline

Comment: I won't be able to help much more. It seems you have an issue with your kerberos configuration. But since you can get a ticket with `kinit`, I don't know what would be the issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I followed these instructions and suddenly it started working, its weird I still dont understand fully what was wrong: 
Manually Connecting an SSSD Client to an Active Directory Domain
https://access.redhat.com/articles/3023951  .

I can now do id and su for an ActiveDir user on Centos7 like $ su user1@adrealm.com with ActiveDir password and login. Bottomline the /etc/hosts , /etc/krb5.conf, /etc/resolv.conf , /etc/sssd/sssd.conf,  /etc/samba/smb.conf need to be carefully checked as all kinds of errors can happen.